# Коализия линий в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Делаю игру на pygame,проблема заключается в том, что мне не получается отобразить коализию линии, хочу чтобы было видно как она врезается в стенку. Пробовал через метод `drawline()`в котором рисуется одна линия, а потом проверяется совпадают ее координаты с координатами стенки.
У нас стена, это квадрат на карте, у которого есть только координаты левого верхнего угла.
Чтобы определить в каком квадрате наш луч, необходимо целочисленно поделить координаты луча и затем умножить их на размер квадрата. Я понимаю это так, но мне не получается написать это в коде

[image: вот как это выглядит]

```
import pygame
import os
import random
import time
import math
from settings import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_HEIGHT, WIN_WEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption("H")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(hero_color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.pillars = None

        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.alive = True


    def drawline(self,win):
        for ray in range(NUM_RAYS):

            xo = self.rect.x - WIN_WEIGHT
            yo = self.rect.y - WIN_HEIGHT
            pygame.draw.line(win,line_color,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y),(xo,yo),2)
            if (xo // TILE * TILE, yo // TILE * TILE) in pillar_cords:
                break


    def update(self):
        self.drawline(win)
        self.rect.x+=self.change_x
        block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.pillars,False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right


        self.rect.y+=self.change_y
        block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.pillars,False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.enemies,False):
            self.alive = False
            self.kill()



    def movement(self):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:        
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                
                self.change_y = -vel

            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                
                self.change_y = vel

            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                
                self.change_x = -vel

            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                
                self.change_x = vel

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                
                self.change_y = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                
                self.change_y = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                
                self.change_x = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                
                self.change_x = 0


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(e_color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.pillars = None


    def update(self):

        self.rect.x+=self.change_x
        block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.pillars,False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right


        self.rect.y+=self.change_y
        block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.pillars,False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

    def movement(self):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:        
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                
                self.change_y = -vel

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                
                self.change_y = vel

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                
                self.change_x = -vel

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                
                self.change_x = vel

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                
                self.change_y = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                
                self.change_y = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                
                self.change_x = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                
                self.change_x = 0


class Pillar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(p_color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.pillars = None
         


all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
pillar_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
pillar_e_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

pillar_cords = [
#walls
[0,0,10,600],
[590,0,10,600],
[10,0,590,10],
[0,590,600,10],
#pillars 1_line
[70,70,20,20],
[210,70,20,20],
[350,70,20,20],
[490,70,20,20],
#pillars 2_line
[70,210,20,20],
[210,210,20,20],
[350,210,20,20],
[490,210,20,20],
#pillars 3_line
[70,350,20,20],
[210,350,20,20],
[350,350,20,20],
[490,350,20,20],
#pillars 4_line
[70,490,20,20],
[210,490,20,20],
[350,490,20,20],
[490,490,20,20],
]

for coord in pillar_cords:
    pillar = Pillar(coord[0],coord[1],coord[2],coord[3])
    pillar_list.add(pillar)
    pillar_e_list.add(pillar)
    all_sprite_list.add(pillar)

#hero making
player = Hero(x,y,width,height)
player.pillars = pillar_list
all_sprite_list.add(player)

#enemy making

enemy = Enemy(e_x,e_y,e_width,e_height)
enemies_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies_list.add(enemy)
enemy.pillars = pillar_e_list
all_sprite_list.add(enemy)


player.enemies = enemies_list

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    player.movement()
    enemy.movement()
    win.fill(background)

    all_sprite_list.update()
    all_sprite_list.draw(win)
    
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    
pygame.quit()
```

Вот настройки

```
# Game setting
background = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
WIN_HEIGHT = 600
WIN_WEIGHT = 600
line_color = (0, 117, 90)

#RAY settings
TILE = 100
W_TILE = 600
NUM_RAYS = 7

#hero settings
hero_pos = (110,110)
x = 110
y = 110
width = 10
height = 10
vel = 5
hero_color = (0, 255, 0)

#pillar settings
p_x = 20
p_y = 20
p_width = 10
p_height = 10
#p_radius = 5
p_color = (158, 76, 0) 
#blue(5, 9, 255)


#enemy settings
e_x = 580
e_y = 580
e_width = 10
e_height = 10
e_vel = 3
e_color = RED
```

Comment: сам помочь не могу, но нашел для тебя статью вот ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553156/pygame-detecting-collision-of-a-rotating-rectangle/59553589#59553589